# Dialog box not showing up properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, dialog

I have a very simple dialog box coded in JQuery, but it isn't showing up properly. The box appears when 'Open Dialog' is clicked, but the layout is all messed up and the overlay doesn't cover the entire page as it should. Can someone tell me what the problem here is?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>


         <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

         <script>       
$(document).ready(function () { 
    function popup() {
    var myPos = {
        my: "center top",
        at: "center top+210",
        of: window
    };

    //Set up the dialog box
    $(".popup").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        position: myPos,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false
    });
    }

    $('#d1').click(function () {
    $('.popup').dialog("open");
});

    popup();
    });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">

.click {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
    color: darkblue;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 210px;
}

    .ui-widget-overlay {
    background: #000;
    opacity: .8;
    -moz-opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
}

    .popup {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #fff;
    }



    .ui-dialog-titlebar {
    background: lightblue;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #D9D6D4;
    }


    </style>

    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="popup" id="box" title="Title">
    <br>Some random content</br>
    <br>More random content</br>
    <p> Blah blah </p>
    </div>
    <div class="click" id="d1">Open dialog</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Seems OK here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ts9huota/

Comment: Yes, I know it works in JSFiddle and other similar sites like CodePen, but when I pull it up as a plain HTML document from NotePad, the format is all messed up. I can't figure out what's wrong. Is it the reference I'm using with Google CDN that's incorrect? Or something else?

Comment: Open your browser's dev tools and see what error messages are in the console.

Comment: I hit F12, but I don't see any error messages in the console?

Answer (score 0):

It's a CSS issue. Add the following in the `head` section

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```